# What is the relationship between Elasticsearh ES_Java_Opts and Kubernetes Resource Limits

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, resources, kubernetes-helm

So i have a Elasticsearch Cluster inside the Kubernetes.

The machine it is running on has 30 GB RAM and 8 cores.

Now according to the thumb rule 50% of the RAM is what we set as `ES_JAVA_OPTS` and remaining is used for file caching.
here it would be 15 GB

Also in the helm chart we have resource requirements mentioned like below:

```
resources:
  limits:
    cpu: 8
    memory: 15Gi
  requests:
    cpu: 8
    memory: 15Gi
```

My question is whether the 50% RAM is of the host machine (Which is 30 GB) or the limit specified in the helm chart 15 GB

Can someone explain how in kubernetes utilise the RAM

Because if it with respect to Host and file caching is not considered as the utilisation of Deployed Application we are OK. But if it within the Resources Limits i need to increase the to 30GB.

**Edit:**

The question here is that if one elasticsearch node used 50% of RAM as Heap and 50% as file caching and i mention the Heap as 15GB (50% of the RAM) in a 30GB machine. so should i mention the resoure limitations in the deployment template as somewhere around 15GB which Heap requires of need 30GB (Say 28GB) that from the rule Elasticsearch need to be able to cache files.

This comes as concern as if pod exceed the mentioned limit on the template at any given moment kubernetes restart the pod.

So in other words i want to know the RAM file caching is come into play in the overall memory usage of the pod or not.

Note: I am using instance storage as primary Storage of the ES Data as this is extremely fast as compare to EBS.

**Conclusion**:

Keep Heap half to the RAM in the system and Mentioned in the resources Limit(if any)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a expert in k8s and docker but what I understand is that, docker container uses the host resources and using resource limit you can have a hard limit on the resources it can consume.

If you put a resource limit of 15GB, than overall your docker container can consume 15GB of host RAM.now whether it will share the file system cache with host or not depends on how you have configured your docker volume.

As docker container have the option to share the file system with host using the [bind volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) or have its own data volume(which is ephemeral and not suited for ES as its a stateful application). in first option it should share the file system cache with host and you should not increase the resource limit further(recommended as you have ES which is stateful) and in second option, as it will use its own file system you have to allocate RAM for its file system cache and have to increase RAM to 30 GB, but you have to give some space for Host OS as well.

Comment: I have edited the question please re-answer according to that as the above answer is not clear @opster-elasticsearch-ninja

Comment: @JugrajSingh, looks like in your case, you are running just one ES conatiner on each host and as you have mentioned, you have already allocated 50% RAM of host to ES heap which is a great start but if you would resource limit of 15GB on your container it would not consume beyond it and looks like mostly file system cache will be part of it, so if you are running just one container on host, better to omit the resources section and thats what I have seen in general

Comment: That's a good suggestion to omit the resources section but on one node i am running kibana alongside elasticsearch node. so to make them honor each others resources i am mentioning limits.
From you above comment what i can say is the file caching is part of RAM usage container so it would be safe to say i should mention limit like around 28GB so that the file caching save it's own memory the the Heap and i can keep the last 1 GB for kibana

Answer (score 0):

Container will always see the node`s memory instead of the container one. In Kubernertes, even though you set a limit for the memory to a container, the container itself is not aware of this limit.

This has an effect on the applications that looks up for the memory available on the system and use that information to decide how memory it wants to reserve.

This is why you setup the [JVM heap size](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/0.9/k8s-jvm-heap-size.html#k8s-jvm-heap-size). Without this specified the JVM will setup the maximum heap size based on the host/node total memory instead of the one available (that you`ve declared as limit) to the container.

Check out [this](https://medium.com/@betz.mark/understanding-resource-limits-in-kubernetes-memory-6b41e9a955f9) article about how limits works in k8s.

Comment: I have edited the question please re-answer according to that as the above answer is not clear